# Gauss Continued Fraction for Hypergeometric Functions

Tags: special-functions, continued-fractions

I would like to calculate the [Gauss Continued Fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_continued_fraction) for this particular Hypergeometric function:
\begin{equation}
_{2}F_{1}\left( 1-\frac{1}{p}, \frac{1}{p}; 1+\frac{1}{p}; x^p \right)
\end{equation}
since it satisfies the transformation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{_{2}F_{1}\left(a+1, b; c+1; z \right)}{_{2}F_{1}\left(a, b; c; z \right)}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{\frac{(a-c)b}{c(c+1)}z}{1+\cdots}}
\end{equation}
for $b=c=-a=1/p$ and $z=x^p, p>1$.
My target is to see whether I could get a good approximation for this function by using this transformation.

I have tried to find a build-in function in *Mathematica* to calculate this continued fraction, but it was not possible.

> I would like to ask if there exists a library where I could possibly find this, or if you could help me write it down on my own.

Comment: there exists a package called HypExp by Maitre, in which an expansion around eps=1/p. Furthermore, there are serveral packages by RISC, which deal with hypergeometric summations. maybe there is something... not sure.

Comment: [...]expansion around eps=1/p might be possible.

Comment: `MathematicalFunctionData["Hypergeometric2F1", "ContinuedFractionRepresentations"]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code to construct the continued fraction expansion to any given order:

```
    f[a_,b_,c_,n_Integer]:=Module[{k},
       k=Floor[n/2];
       Which[n==1,1,
          EvenQ[n],-((b+k-1)(c-a+k-1))/((c+2k-2)(c+2k-1)),
          OddQ[n], -((a+k)(c-b+k))/((c+2k-1)(c+2k))]]/;n>0;

    cfrac[m_]=ContinuedFractionK[f[a,b,c,n]z^(n-1),1,{n,1,m+1}];
```

Give it a try.  Just type, for example, "cfrac[4]".  I haven't checked convergence properties for your case of interest.

Comment: Seems pretty good, thank you! I will try to check whether convergence holds.